# Mergesort recursion error

Tags: python, mergesort

i coded this mergesort code in python.The function merge is working well when i am calling it seperately,its sorting two different sorted lists.But when i am using it in real merge sort recursion problem,it is not doing its intended work.I am uploading my code please help me regarding this issue

```
def merge(list,p,q,r):

    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    list3=[]
    i=0
    j=0
    for a in list[:q+1]:
        list1.append(a)
    list1.append(99999999999)

    for b in list[q+1:]:
        list2.append(b)
    list2.append(9999999999999999999999999)
    for k in range(len(list)):
        if list1[i]<list2[j]:
            list3.insert(k,list1[i])
            i=i+1
        else:
            list3.insert(k,list2[j])
            j=j+1
        return list3




def mergesort(list,p,r):

    if p<r:

      q=(p+r)/2
      mergesort(list,p,q)
      mergesort(list,q+1,r)
      merge(list,p,q,r)


list=[1,5,7,8,2,4,6,9]

mergesort(list,0,7)

print list
```

There is no intendation error

the output is :

```
[1, 5, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9]
```

its printing the same as the list
not sorting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not modifing list inside your function '`merge`'

You either need to modify the `list` or `return` new `list` , you are doing neither

You can return list3 from merge function
and modify mergesort as:

```
def mergesort(list,p,r):
    if p<r:
      q=(p+r)/2
      mergesort(list,p,q)
      mergesort(list,q+1,r)
      list =merge(list,p,q,r)
```

Hi made it work:
Use

```
 def merge(list,p,q,r):

    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    list3=[]
    i=0
    j=0
    for a in list[:q+1]:
        list1.append(a)
    list1.append(99999999999)

    for b in list[q+1:]:
        list2.append(b)
    list2.append(9999999999999999999999999)
    for k in range(len(list)):
        if list1[i]<list2[j]:
            list3.insert(k,list1[i])
            i=i+1
        else:
            list3.insert(k,list2[j])
            j=j+1
    return list3




def mergesort(list,p,r):

    if p<r:

      q=(p+r)/2
      mergesort(list,p,q)
      mergesort(list,q+1,r)
      list = merge(list,p,q,r)
      return list

list=[1,5,7,8,2,4,6,9]

list = mergesort(list,0,7)

print list
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little.I need to solve this ,actually new to python

Comment: you mean to say i return a list in merge function.i did that but still its not working at all

Comment: i returned list3 in the merge function

Comment: mithilesh i tried still the code is not working,its giving the same output,i returned list3 from merge and did list=merge(list,p,q,r), and after running the function its giving the same output.i am helpless..

Comment: mithilesh is it working in your ide? it is not working in mine though ,its giving the same output. the same unsorted array